# Removing items in list not corresponding to max value in another list

Tags: python, list, replace

```
model_names = ['is1', 'is5', 'is10', 'im1', 'im5', 'im10']
```

As an example,

```
models = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]
```

The maximum of the list is 0.3, which corresponds to model names 'im1' and 'im10'. I'd like the function

```
dominant_model(models)
```

to return

```
['im1', 'im10']
```

i.e, the most 'dominant' model(s).

---

Here's my code which does the job, but I'd like to know if there's a shorter way of doing the same thing rather than all of the conditionals:

```
def dominant_model(models):
    m = max(models)
    dom_models = [i for i,j in enumerate(models) if j==m]
    for i in range(len(dom_models)):
        if dom_models[i]==0:
            dom_models[i]=model_names[0]
        elif dom_models[i]==1:
            dom_models[i]=model_names[1]
        elif dom_models[i]==2:
            dom_models[i]=model_names[2]
        elif dom_models[i]==3:
            dom_models[i]=model_names[3]
        elif dom_models[i]==4:
            dom_models[i]=model_names[4]
        elif dom_models[i]==5:
            dom_models[i]=model_names[5]
    return dom_models
```

Answer (score 9):

After finding the max `m = max(model)`, zip the model names to the values and take the names where the value is equal to `m` .

```
def dominant(names, values):
    m = max(values)
    return [name for name, value in zip(names, values) if value == m]
```

---

**Demo**

```
>>> model_names = ['is1', 'is5', 'is10', 'im1', 'im5', 'im10']
>>> model_values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]
>>> dominant(model_names, model_values)
['im1', 'im10']
```

Comment: This is really elegant

Answer (score 0):

Use two loops:

```
def dominant_model(models):
    m = max(models)
    dom_models = [i for i,j in enumerate(models) if j==m]
    for i in range(len(dom_models)):
        for j in range(6):
            if dom_models[i]==j:
                dom_models[i]=model_names[j]
    return dom_models
```